# How can I get the Stacktrace of this error of fix it?

Tags: java, kotlin, ktor

Hey i try to using Ktor with the Kotlin Hands on. But I have a Problem when access the Web Page with "/".

```
        embeddedServer(Netty, port) {
            install(FreeMarker) {
                templateLoader = ClassTemplateLoader(this::class.java.classLoader, "templates")
                outputFormat = HTMLOutputFormat.INSTANCE
            }
            routing {
                static("/static") {
                    resources("files")
                }
                get("/") {
                    call.respond(FreeMarkerContent("index.ftl", mapOf("entries" to blogEntries), ""))
                }
            }
        }.start(wait = false)
```

There is my code i use. I cant find an error there is only this message in the console:

`[eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] INFO ktor.application - Unhandled: GET - /, io failed`

Is there anyone who has an idea how can I fix that error?

Comment: I don't know this library but looks like it handled the exception on the inside. The message is a pretty standard logging message, if you have some sort of logger configured for the project you might find the stack trace there. Otherwise check the library's page for community support, this might be a common issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact line where that message is generated is in `io.ktor.server.engine.logFailure`: https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/2e1b0046e4235865da7cbbfbf2e887f410775278/ktor-server/ktor-server-host-common/jvm/src/io/ktor/server/engine/DefaultEnginePipeline.kt#L107

```kotlin
private fun ApplicationEnvironment.logFailure(call: ApplicationCall, cause: Throwable) {
   ...
            is IOException -> log.info("$status: $logString, io failed: ${cause.message ?: "unknown error"}")
   ...
}
```

Add a breakpoint on this line. Then when your app fails, `cause` will contain the real exception.

In my case it was an error in the FreeMarker template. Which is weird, because usually those exceptions print normally. This time it only printed `Unhandled: <route>, io failed`.

It seems that this is a bug in Ktor: these exceptions are thrown in normal behavior, and frequently enough that you don't want a full stacktrace. But sometimes (like in this case) the exception isn't normal and you do want a stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the [CallLogging](https://ktor.io/docs/logging.html#call_logging) feature and [routes tracing](https://ktor.io/docs/tracing-routes.html) to troubleshoot your problem.